# upload and view a pdf in R shiny

Tags: r, pdf, shiny

I have a simple shiny app in R for reading a PDF file from the user and display it.  I can't seem to get it to work. On the shiny server in the www directory I see a 1 KB file with the name "myreport.pdf" that just has the first character

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Testing File upload"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file_input', 'upload file ( . pdf format only)', accept = c('.pdf'))
    ),

    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("pdfview")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observe({
    req(input$file_input)
    test_file <- readBin(input$file_input$datapath, what="character") 
    writeBin(test_file, "www/myreport.pdf")
  })


  output$pdfview <- renderUI({
    tags$iframe(style="height:600px; width:100%", src="myreport.pdf")
  })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the issue is with the binary reading and writing. Instead trying to copy the files using `file.copy` seems to work. Also I've taken the `iframe` inside `observeEvent` for the iframe to update every time the pdf is uploaded in the same session.

Updated Code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Testing File upload"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file_input', 'upload file ( . pdf format only)', accept = c('.pdf'))
    ),

    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("pdfview")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observe({
    req(input$file_input)

     #test_file <- readBin(input$file_input$datapath, what="raw") 

     #writeBin(test_file, "myreport.pdf")

     #cat(input$file_input$datapath)

     file.copy(input$file_input$datapath,"www", overwrite = T)



  output$pdfview <- renderUI({
    tags$iframe(style="height:600px; width:100%", src="0.pdf")
  })

  })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I've tried running your code and upload a pdf, but in the pdfview it just says Not Found, any ideas why? thanks!

Comment: I changed src = "0.pdf" to "input$file_input$datapath" but it displays blank information

Comment: You need to create folder `www` before running the above chunk and subsitute 
`file.copy(input$file_input$datapath, "www", overwrite = T)` into `file.copy(input$file_input$datapath, "www/0.pdf", overwrite = T)`

Comment: Just in case you still encounter the issue described by Subaru Spirit: I tried this code. First got the same result as Subaru. After some time I noticed that I have to save the app after copy and paste. The it runs. With just copy paste select all and run it shows an empty placeholder with "not found" text.

Answer (score 1):

Update: the code above works perfectly.

Still, I spent off and on 5+ hours attempting to troubleshoot the:

“Not Found” error—that occurred across browsers in MacOS.

Solution (for me):

1. Copy and paste the code above into a new R-file
2. Create a new folder “[appfolder]” (as an example)
3. Save the code/R file outlaid above as “app.R” in the "[appfolder]"
4. Either create a folder within the “[appfolder]” labeled “www” or insert the following line of code into the server:

dir.create(“www”) ## www folder will be created for you

Run "app.R" and PDF upload and output works for me (hopefully this helps others who are stuck).