# Upload and viewer PDF Shiny error - Not Found

Tags: r, shiny

I want to user to upload pdf file and then view it - including basic functions like zoom in and zoom out.

But I am getting error

```r
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(    
    titlePanel("Testing File upload"),    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            fileInput('file_input', 'upload file ( . pdf format only)', accept = c('.pdf'))
        ),        
        mainPanel(
            uiOutput("pdfview")
        )
    )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {    
    observe({
        req(input$file_input)

        #test_file <- readBin(input$file_input$datapath, what="raw")         
        #writeBin(test_file, "myreport.pdf")        
        #cat(input$file_input$datapath)        

        file.copy(input$file_input$datapath,"www", overwrite = T)
        output$pdfview <- renderUI({
            tags$iframe(style="height:600px; width:100%", src="0.pdf")
        })        
    })    
})
```

I am getting: `bot found error in viewer. "Not Found"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I maight not get it right (so make sure to correct me if I am wrong) but: why is your source `0.pdf` ? Should not it be `input$file_input$datapath` ? Or even:

```r
# in your server:
# ... 
# saves the file name only
file.name <- gsub("^.*/(.*)$", "\\1", input$file_input$datapath)
file.copy(input$file_input$datapath,"www", overwrite = T)
file.path <- paste0("www/", file.name)

output$pdfview <- renderUI({
        tags$iframe(style="height:600px; width:100%", src=file.path)
    })
# ...
```

Comment: I've tried to change 0.pdf to input$file_input$datapath but it still didn't work, I think the author's question comes from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47395465/upload-and-view-a-pdf-in-r-shiny