# Creating a shiny app that uploads and reads in a pdf file

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a Shiny app that allows a user to upload a PDF and views that pdf in the app. I have create code to built this app and it works but the uploaded file does not appear in the app. Please view my code below and help me see what I am missing. Thanks

```
library(pdftools)
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application 
ui <- fluidPage(
   
   # Application title
   titlePanel("Upload file"),
   
   sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel(
       fileInput('file1', 'Upload PDF file', accept = c('.pdf'))
             #multiple = TRUE,
             #accept = c("pdf",
                        #".pdf")),
     ),
     
    mainPanel(
      
      uiOutput("pdfview")
      
      )
   )
)


# Define server logic required
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
    mypdf<-reactive({
      req(input$file1)
      
      inFile <- input$file1$datapath
      
      if (is.null(inFile)){
      return(NULL)
      }else{
        return(paste(inFile))
        

        
      }
      
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47395465/upload-and-view-a-pdf-in-r-shiny