# Unable to Display pdf file RShiny

Tags: r, pdf, shiny

When i run the code and browse the pdf from my system the Document Viewer says "Not Found" although the other tabs creating graphs based on pdf's content are working fine.
I am adding the relevant part of code here as I cannot share the entire code.

```
ui.R                    
tabItem(tabName="Views",
                            fluidRow(
                              tabBox(width=14,
                                     tabPanel(tags$em("Document Viewer",style="font-size:140%"),
                                              
                                              column(width = 8,
                                                     uiOutput("pdfview"))
                                              
                                     )


server <- function(input, output) {
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=800*1024^2) 
  
  mypdf_list<-reactive({
    
    inFile <- input$file1
    
  })
  
  observe({
    req(input$file1)
    pdf_file = readBin(input$file1$datapath, what="character")
    
  })
 
  output$pdfview <- renderUI({
   tags$iframe(style="height:600px; width:100%", src="input$file1$datapath")
  })
```

Comment: That should be `src=input$file1$datapath` (no quotes), but I'm not sure this will work, because 1) Shiny will search this file in the **www** subfolder, 2) this is not a HTML file.

Comment: Perhaps this might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47395465/upload-and-view-a-pdf-in-r-shiny