# How ca i display a PDF into my Shiny APP?

Tags: r, pdf, shiny, shinydashboard

A little explain.
Im triying to create a dashoboard which display a pdf file , by the user type the name
into a TextInput.

Program must browse into the folder www and display the pdf in the dashboard boddy
The problem its , the program work and find the pdf , but it is open into the pdf program
no inside my Shiny App.

Here its my code.

Second question , how can i omite that the user do not type ".pdf" in the textinput,
i want that the user only type the pdf file name without .pdf

Thank you !!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="PDF Display" ),
  dashboardSidebar(id= NULL, LIST= NULL),
  dashboardBody(
  
  textInput(inputId = "select_pdf", 
                            label = "Buscador de WB", 
                            placeholder = "Escibe el WB en MAYUSCULAS"),
 
                  uiOutput("pdf_viewer")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
 output$pdf_viewer<- renderUI({
     tags$iframe(style="height:600px; width:100%", src=input$select_pdf)
     
     
   })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Q2: if `!grepl("\\.pdf$", filename)` then add it yourself. Though honestly, from a UI/UX perspective, I would not require my users manually type in the entire filename, which is prone to typos, case sensitivity, and similar. I'd think another approach would be to `list.files(...)`, and then use the return in `selectInput`.

Comment: Q1: you say the PDFs are in a different directory, but I don't see anywhere where you actually define the path of where the files are located. If the user types in `quux`, and (taking my first comment) you add `.pdf` to that, you have `quux.pdf`, but since you said this should match against files in the `www/` directory ... how do you expect R to guess that? Why wouldn't R also look in the `www2`, `inst`, `data`, `tmp`, and `..` (to name a few) directories?

Comment: Cheers , well maybe i misunderstanding the files are in www folder where my scrips are. my problem still in , shiny app open the pdf file in pdf program , no inside my shiny app

Comment: Perhaps the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47395465/upload-and-view-a-pdf-in-r-shiny) might suffice.