# How to upload PDF File, Display it and Remove it on Shiny R

Tags: r, pdf, iframe, shiny, shinydashboard

I have been tried to upload PDF file and try to display in Shiny it but it's not working.

I tried using the script from here [upload and view a pdf in R shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47395465/upload-and-view-a-pdf-in-r-shiny) but i got result Not Found.

Is there anyone can help

**UPDATE**

Thanks a lot for @YBS for the advise, the reference link that shown above are work properly.

After I create the www folder it runs well and it's must run from the browser

[image]

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Testing File upload"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file_input', 'upload file ( . pdf format only)', accept = c('.pdf')),
      fileInput('file_input2', 'upload file2 ( . pdf format only)', accept = c('.pdf'))
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("pdfview"),
      uiOutput("pdfview2")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  observe({
    req(input$file_input)
    
    file.copy(input$file_input$datapath,"www\\pdf1", overwrite = T)
    
    output$pdfview <- renderUI({
      tags$iframe(style="height:600px; width:100%", src="pdf1\\0.pdf")
    })
    
  })
  
  observe({
    req(input$file_input2)
    
    file.copy(input$file_input2$datapath,"www\\pdf2", overwrite = T)
    
    output$pdfview2 <- renderUI({
      tags$iframe(style="height:600px; width:100%", src="pdf2\\0.pdf")
    })
    
  })
  
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Please provide examples and code you have tried so far

Comment: The answer in your link works fine for me.  Please note that `file.copy` keeps a copy of your pdf file in `www` folder with the name `0.pdf`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @YBS I should create www folder first and it's worked